# SQL Server:subquery returns more then 1 value

Tags: sql-server, subquery

i have two tables
table one contains

> a b c d e f

and table two contains

> b c d e f g h i j k l

i want to show the data from table two and the data should not be used in table one (`k l`)
here the value `k and l` should be printed

in my example i have written the query

```
select comarea from companyarea where comarea !=(select area from companyallot where comname='24' and zone='west' and location='mumbai')
```

but the error is coming

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

here in my example i want to use the area which are not being used in the table called companyallot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Where condition "=" operator will deal with single value, "in" operator will deal with multiple values. So instead of using != use "not in" operator as below.

```
SELECT comarea FROM companyarea 
     WHERE comarea NOT IN
     (SELECT area FROM companyallot WHERE comname='24' AND zone='west' AND      
     location='mumbai')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `!=` with `NOT IN` operator

```
SELECT COMAREA FROM COMPANYAREA WHERE COMAREA NOT IN  (
        SELECT AREA
        FROM COMPANYALLOT
        WHERE COMNAME = '24'
            AND ZONE = 'WEST'
            AND LOCATION = 'MUMBAI'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN` operator works fine as long as there is no `NULL` value being returned by the sub-query but it all goes pear shape as soon as there is even one null value in the sub-query.

A safer option would be to use `EXISTS/NOT EXISTS` operator, something like...

```
select a.comarea 
from companyarea a
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                 from companyallot t 
                 where t.comname='24' 
                   and t.zone='west' 
                   and t.location='mumbai'
                   and a.comarea = t.area)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things in order to make it work:

-> Used a multi-value operator NOT IN (OR) IN

-> Although your case does not specify it, but it is always good if you treat NULLS well in advanced, by using NVL in your inner subquery results.

-> NOT EXISTS Operator should still work